# How to Create a Sell Button Code In Visual Studio C# with SQL Server as database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio C# and I'm having a conflict on how to create a sell button as well how can I get the total amount of product that had been sold here is my code

```
try
{
    if (txtID.Text != "" && txtCategory.Text != "" && 
        txtName.Text != "" && txtQty.Text != "" && 
        txtQty.Text != "" && PriceText.Text != "" && 
        SuppNameText.Text != "")
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Sold_Inventory 
            (ProductName, Description, Category, Quantity_Sold, Price,
             TotalAmount, SuppliersName) 
             VALUES(@ProductName, @Description, @Category, @Quantity, @Price,
             @Supplier)
             WHERE TotalAmount = @Quantity * @Price", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", txtCategory.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQty.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", PriceText.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", SuppNameText.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Quantity 
               FROM Inventory SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity");
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQty.Text);

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        ClearTextbox();

        btnSearch.Enabled = true;
        txtSearch.Enabled = true;
        groupBox4.Enabled = true;
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
        ClearTextbox();
        DisabledTextbox();
        btnAdd.Enabled = true;

        RefreshDGV(this.dataGridView1);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You left an empty field!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: INSERT INTO doesn't require  a WHERE condition, instead an UPDATE without a WHERE updates everything

Comment: and that is *one very odd where clause* any way. you should want to update a specific item

Comment: sorry im new in coding can u please explain it to me so i can understand and also when i try to press sold then check my database quantity stays the same

Comment: And you tag this with MySql but then you use the classes from the SqlClient library that is specific for Sql Server. Which database are you using?

Comment: MySQL management studio

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Comment: should i do this code SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand ("Update TotalAmount From Sold_Inventory SET TotalAmount = @Quantity*@Price");  for updating the total amount?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the first SqlCommand is wrong.
INSERT INTO doesn't require a WHERE clause and you are missing one parameter placeholder in your query text.

So the first fix is around your command text

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Sold_Inventory 
     (ProductName,Description,Category,Quantity_Sold,Price,
      TotalAmount,SuppliersName) 
      VALUES(@ProductName,@Description,@Category,@Quantity,@Price,
      @TotalAmount, @Supplier)", con);
```

Now calculate the value for the @TotalAmount parameter in code like this....

```
decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text) * 
                Convert.ToDecimal(PriceText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", total);
```

Finally, the command that decrements the quantity should identify the exact record for the product that you have sold. Here the WHERE clause is fundamental.

I suppose that your Product table has a record for the product that you have sold identified by something like a ProductID primary key. 
(Also you need to add the connection when you build the command)

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"Update Inventory 
           SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity
           WHERE ProductID = @productID", con);
```

There are other considerations to your code. First, forget the AddWithValue method. It is an easy shortcut, but it can create a lot of problems if you pass a string as parameter value and the column that receives the value is not a text field (the automatic conversion from string to decimal could fail because the localization of your client code doesn't match the rules used by the database engine)

Better use always the Add method specifying the datatype of the parameter.
For example, the Price column probably wants a decimal not a string, so

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price;
```

Of course the same applies to all other values. Don't let AddWithValue figure out what do you mean with your parameter. Be explicit.

Comment: what if i dont have a primary key on table and they are mostly stand alone table?

Comment: How do you identify the product sold? I suppose that you have more than one product right? Do you use simply the name of the product? (wrong) Anyway if you execute an UPDATE without a WHERE you update every record in that table, also the records that store the quantity of different products.....

Comment: o yeah sorry i forgot identify it by product name

Comment: And what happen if you need to rename the product (not an impossible thing in my experience)? However the WHERE clause could easily changed to _"....WHERE ProductName = @ProductName"_

Comment: i got a fix name on each of every product i had also i did try your codes i cant seem to make the quantity work maybe its just the place where i put it

Comment: i mean i also got an update button so i can change my products freely

Comment: Did you get any exception message? What is not working? Did you add the parameters for cmd1? (@Quantity and @ProductName)

Comment: its says that executenonquery connection has not been properly initializzed

Comment: Oh yes, the second command is not linked to the connection, fixing it

Comment: same executenonquery

Comment: Did you add the connection to the second command? The cmd1? and of course you don't close the connection before executing the second query right?

Comment: yup i didnt i put the cmd 1 after the cmd.executequery()